# How to choose which url must use which page.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a URL like: `http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/writer-archive/?writer=example` and I want Wordpress to  send us to `writer-archive.php` when we visit it.

Comment: Very unclear question. But if you click on that link you showed, you're already on writer-archive.php.

Comment: so if you click on the writer-archive.php you want to go like it as: writer-archive/?writer=example. like .php gets replaced to /

Comment: What do you mean by *WordPress send us to*? Do you mean "WordPress renders content from the database that has a slug like `writer-archive.php`? Or do you mean the PHP server executes `writer-archive.php` and returns the results from that?

Comment: is 'writer-archive.php' a custom page template that you'd like to use?

Comment: @AlexThomas Yes, it is.

Comment: @Blowski to be clear, I want to use writer-archive.php codes for loop(s) and other stuff to create a archive for articles writer.

Comment: So you're trying to change something in a theme? In WordPress **everything** on the public pages goes through `index.php`, and WordPress calls the theme files to generate the HTML. So build a theme, and put the loops into the theme files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is 'writer-archive.php' a custom page template that you'd like to use?
> –  Alex Thomas 8 mins ago
>
> @AlexThomas Yes, it is. –  Mehdi Hoseini 3 mins ago

Im going to assume that you've made a custom post type 'writer' therefore you want to call you custom archive template 'archive-writer.php'

See more info here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates